# How can I play Diablo 3 and WoW behind a DD-WRT router?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

My roommates and I like to play diablo 3 and wow at the same time, but we experience frequent disconnects.  If one of the machines is in the DMZ on the router it doesn't disconnect when the other two do.  I've turned the router firewall off and this does nothing to help.  Any ideas?  Can I just forward all the appropriate ports to ALL of the computers?

Router model: FR-300RTR(rebranded d-link)

Router firmware: DD-WRT c24-sp2

Router firewall: off

UPnP: on

dmz: off

manual port forwarding: off

All machines are running windows 7

Comment: You shouldn't have to forward any port to any computer for either World of Warcraft _or_ Diablo 3. You don't run server applications that need to be connectable from the outside world - _you_ are making the outwards connections to the WOW/D3 servers. The only exception is that patches are distributed via Bittorrent, which will run "smoother" if you are connectable, but gaming-wise it should be no difference. Don't put machines in DMZ - that opens up all ports and could compromise security. Perhaps your router is simply faulty.

Comment: Have you tried this with another router?

Comment: I was originally using some generic Belkin router from Walmart.  With it we were experiencing disconnects as well, but only at load screens.  Now I am using a router my stepdad gave me that is loaded with the dd-wrt firmware

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are serving the game (which is not the case for wow or diablo 3) you should not need to open any ports. All will be done automagically.

The problem should then be in your router or network connection. Since in the DMZ you have no more problems then it's probably a router thing. If this assertion is correct you should see much less issues with two people and even less or no issues with only one person at a time.

Try using a more powerful router or upgrading your firmware to a more flexible opensource solution like Tomato or DD-WRT (if compatible). These should give you a better insight into what is going on with your router and would allow you to turn off unneeded services to improve performance.

Using DD-WRT the status tab will give you a lot of information. Focus on free memory and active connections, but you might as well check CPU load and look for dropped packets.
If you conclude that indeed it's you router causing the issues you have several options:

1. Flash a version of DD-WRT that is easier on resources. The mini version could be enough for your needs and might serve you better in terms of performance.
2. Turn stuff off. Firewall would be the most important but since that one is off already go for other stuff. Google is your friend.
3. Overclock your router. Google is your friend.
4. Get a new router... this is the best option here. 100€ can buy you a bad ass router and between the three of you it's not that much money. Make sure you can take it back if it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I am using the dd-wrt firmware.  I should have mentioned that.  Knowing that, how can I gain better insight into what is going on with my router?  That sounds incredibly broad but what I am really looking for here is terms to google.

Comment: @Jake - It does not matter that you are running dd-wrt.  I have used it.  The default configuration allows you to play both games without changing a single setting.

Comment: @Ramhound: It matters since it's likely that he is hitting some hardware limit on the router that is causing the dropped connections.
Jake: I'll add a couple of things you can try.